# Resistors/capacitor used in connecting 23LC1024 SRAM 1 Mbit

Tags: arduino-uno, resistor, sram, capacitors

Yesterday I received by 23LC1024 SRAM with 1 Mbit memory.

I tried to search for some libraries and ways how to connect it.

So I searched around on internet first for the connections and saw some different ways of doing it, especially regarding the pullup resistors.

E.g. in [Example1](https://thearduinoandme.wordpress.com/tutorials/external-sram-23lc1024/) two resistors are mentioned for pin 3 and 7. 
In [Example 2](https://ucexperiment.wordpress.com/2013/02/26/more-memory-arduino-and-23lc1024/) only one resistor is used.
In [YouTube example 3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eIP_w5uizNw&t=417s) three resistors and a capacitor is used. See around 5:25.

My questions:

1. Is one of those three better (and why)?
2. Is the capacitor in the youtube example 3 connected to GND or 5v? I cannot map the schema with the breadboard since the capacitor should run between +5 and GND but I don't see the +5 or GND connection (depending on where the capacitor is connected to which I cannot see or deduce).

Btw, I got it working with the 2 resistor solution but just wondering if example 1 is good enough or example 3 is better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better to use external pull-up resistor at least on `CS`. It's because MCU pins are configured as INPUTs without pull-ups just after the startup/restart before it gets into the `setup()`.

Also I'd recommend decoupling capacitor as close as possible to the SRAM power supply pins (between `Vcc` and `Gnd`). You can google what the decoupling capacitors are (they are also called bypass capacitors).

Edit: First two examples are supposed to be on bread board. So it's not so hard just rewire it, if you have to use for example `/HOLD` too. However the third example is soldered on prototype board and therfore it's not so easy to rewire it. That's why `NU` and `/HOLD` inputs are connected to the Vcc through `10k` resistor. If you have to use `/HOLD` in the future, it's easier to just solder new connection, than rewire hardwired connection to the Vcc.

About decoupling caps - there are even sockets with builtin cap:
[image: 8pin socket with decoupling capacitor]

Comment: thank you very much ... some more reading to do, thanks for the right naming/functionality of the capacitors. In the example of the youtube video (3th example) at 5:25, pins 1 and 3 (and 7) have a resistor and the capacitor is going from those resistors to either GND or +5v (I cannot see) but in the schematics the pins 1, 3, 7 and 8 all goes to the capacitor from +5 to GND so I do not see how the schematics and the breadboard map? Can you explain this?

Comment: @MichelKeijzers Updated. Btw, it's even more difficult if you have custom board :D

Comment: Thank you again KIIV .. for the coming months I will stay away from prototype boards probably ... so I will use the breadboard solution I have now, but add the capacitor on the breadboard as in example 3. Still not sure exactly how to place the capacitor in my case, however, I will first read and maybe it gets clear automatically.

Comment: @MichelKeijzers Like this: http://i.imgur.com/vRvhIhy.png (it's pretty much the same for 8pins chips)

Comment: Thanks ... so in my case in http://www.bing.com/images/search?view=detailV2&ccid=%2f7BbflDG&id=B3D333677F7B9C059EC35C0294DFAEA2F33F7015&q=23lc1024&simid=607995735057761174&selectedIndex=11&ajaxhist=0 I have to put e.g. a 0.1nF between pins 4 and 8?

Comment: Ah That is really clear (the pic you added). I guess always (or mostly) pins 4 and 8 are +5V and GND (or at least the two opposite pins) ... I just have a few ICs yet, so I haven't noticed it.